# Style "filter operators" ComboBox of Telerik RadDataFilter

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

So I have a `RadDataFilter`

```
<telerik:RadDataFilter x:name="radDataFilter" />
```

Problem: I want to hide the filter operators combobox. *(the one that has "Contains", "Is Equal To" ... etc. etc. etc.)*

Searching Telerik's [website](http://www.telerik.com/help/wpf/raddatafilter-styles-and-templates-template-structure.html) and [forum](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/wpf/data-filter/filtercontrol-styling.aspx) [led](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/silverlight/data-filter/readonly-filter-descriptor.aspx) [me](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/wpf/data-filter/datafilter-style.aspx) to believe the only way was to override the whole `ControlTemplate`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I came up with was to style base on a trigger:

```
<Style TargetType="telerik:RadComboBox">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="x:Name" Value="PART_SimpleFilterOperatorComboBox">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers> 
</Style>
```

You can name it and then set a style just for that RadDataFilter like so:

```
<telerik:RadDataFilter x:name="radDataFilter">
    <telerik:RadDataFilter.Resources>
         <Style TargetType="telerik:RadComboBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource HiddenOperatorStyle}" />
    </telerik:RadDataFilter.Resources>
</telerik:RadDataFilter>
```